# Convert array to object with saving original index field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array that is sorted in the following way

```
var items = [2.99, 5.99, 23.99, 1.99];
items.sort(function(a,b) { return a - b;});
```

This outputs the following:

```
[1.99, 2.99, 5.99, 23.99]
```

But I need a way to sort it but keep an index of the original index, e.g.

```
[3: 1.99, 0: 2.99, 1: 5.99, 2:23.99]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map it to an array of objects.

So in the resulting array, each member is an object with an `n` property that holds the number, and an `i` property that holds the original index.

You can then iterate that array and get the data like normal.

```js
var items = [2.99, 5.99, 23.99, 1.99];

var arr_of_objs = items.map(function(n, i) {
    return { n:n, i:i };
}).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.n - b.n;
});

arr_of_objs.forEach(function(obj, i) {
    this.textContent += "number: " + obj.n + ", orig idx: " + obj.i + ", new idx: " + i + "\n";
}, document.querySelector("pre"));
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var items = [2.99, 5.99, 23.99, 1.99];

var sortable = [];
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  sortable.push([i, items[i]]);
}
sortable.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a[1] - b[1]
});

console.log(sortable);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not possible in JS get sorting in this case. JS understands array only as [0: 1.99, 1:2.99, 3:23.99] -- you cannot change order of indexes. But you can use array of arrays or array of object to solve the problem.

```
var items = [2.99, 5.99, 23.99, 1.99];


function PreserveKeysSorting(arr) {
    var arr = arr
        obj = [];

    for(i in arr) {
        obj.push({index: i, value: arr[i]});
    }

    obj.sort(function(a,b) { return a.value - b.value;});

    return obj;
}

console.log(items);
console.log(PreserveKeysSorting(items));
```

Live Demo -- http://jsfiddle.net/u1g0xsap/1/

Answer (score 1):

The array that you want as a result is not valid, but you can do something like this:

First make an array that contains objects that persists the index:

```
var itemsObj = []; 
items.forEach(function(value, index) { 
    itemsObj.push({
        value: value, 
        index: index 
    });
});
```

Then you can sort them like this:

```
items.sort(function(a,b) { return a.value - b.value;});
```

and you will get an arary of objects like this

```
 [{index:3, value: 1.99}, {index: 0, value: 2.99}, {index: 1, value: 5.99}, {index:2, value:23.99}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use two arrays and `indexOf()` method:

```
// Variables
var items = items_sort = [2.99, 5.99, 23.99, 1.99];
var order = new Array();

// Sort array
items_sort.sort(function(a,b) { return a - b;});

// Get order
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    order[i] = items.indexOf(items_sort[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hardcode the index into the array:

```
var items = [2.99, 5.99, 23.99, 1.99]
var itemsWithIndex = [];
for (i=0; i<items.length; i++) { itemsWithIndex[i] = [i+1, items[i]]; }
itemsWithIndex.sort(function(a,b) { return a[1]-b[1]; });
```

Note that an auxiliary variable (itemsWithIndex) was added for clarity, but you can also just update the original array:

```
var items = [2.99, 5.99, 23.99, 1.99]
for (i=0; i<items.length; i++) { items[i] = [i+1, items[i]]; }
items.sort(function(a,b) { return a[1]-b[1]; });
```